# Angular2 basic seed in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, angular2-seed

I am new to Angular2 and WebStorm. I am looking for a basic project seed for WebStorm that I can start play around with Angular2.

There are lots of them online, but I can't find a single one that walks me through what are the basic packages that I need and why I need them.

Is any of you aware of a tutorial that can help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are new to Angular2, just start with [Angular2 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). You can create a new empty project in WebStorm and start populating it with your stuff following the steps in tutorial, or download the project stub from https://github.com/angular/quickstart and open project folder in WebStorm using `File | Open`.

Note that WebStorm itself doesn't force you to use this or that project skeleton, generator, bundler, etc. - just use whatever you want... see also https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/04/angular-2-workflow-in-webstorm - you may find this blog post helpful

Comment: Thank you, the git quickstart is exactly what I was looking for !